# Dual Booting Sony Vaio with 4 Primary Partitions Already

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, vaio

I have been trying to dual-boot my Sony Vaio for a few weeks now.  I am able to get to get to the installation menu, however, I am not given the option of running Ubuntu alongside Windows 7.  So, I chose "Something else" and see this:
[image]

I seem to have four primary partitions already.  Does this mean that I would have to delete a partition and then free up space from another?  If so, how would I go about this?  Which partition would I be able to delete without messing up my hard drive and losing everything?

Regardless, I don't understand why Ubuntu is not recognizing my Windows 7 partition.

I have done quite a bit of research and have noticed that a lot of people have had a hard time dual-booting with their Vaio's, but I have not seen a solution that pertains to my situation.

I have also included an image of my partitions in Windows:
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have an UEFI install with gpt partitioning. gpt does not really have primary partitions as they all are the same, or all partitions are primary and you can have as many as you want. Standard limit is 128 partitions.

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Some specific info on Sony

http://www.slideshare.net/Tinydile/vaio-pro13-win8ubuntu1310uefi